# Is there a way to freeze a column in a vuetify data table?

Tags: vuetify.js

I cannot find a good solution to this without using a vuetify fork, which isn't stable and appears to be the older version anyway.  I will link to it in the comments.

The only way I can think to do this is to line up two data tables side by side, which creates problems in itself.  I know there are other plugins/libraries that allow this, but I would really prefer to stick with vuetify.  Has anyone had success with doing this?

My project is to create a grid that allows the user to set up a rotation.  Each column (after the first one) is a dynamically created week (Friday's date is column header) that shows if there is an opening in a given organization.  The struggle is to get enough weeks to show up on the screen at once.  The first column is the organization. So, I want to know what organization my row is in for a given week as I scroll to the right.  That's why I need to freeze the first column.

I'm open to other solutions - like a different way to show the header, perhaps, that would allow me to fit in 52 weeks worth of dates.

Comment: https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/dqZvXr

Answer (score 8):

I am also searching for a solution to this. The nearest I have found is this complex bit of CSS [Source](https://github.com/zhitnyakov/vuetify-fixed-columns/blob/master/src/components/TableWithFixedColumn.vue)

```
<style>
  table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1),
  table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) {
    position: sticky !important;
    position: -webkit-sticky !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    background: white;
  }
  table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
</style>
```

However, it doesn't quite work for my case.

I have something like this

```
Account           Jan    Feb    Mar
123456             50     51    52
123458             38     39    32
123600             20     21    22
```

So what I am looking for is the Excel equivalent of putting a freeze panes on the Jan,123456 intersection, so that the months stay in place when scrolling down, and the Account column stays in place when scrolling to the right.

I set the fixed-header and :height property on the v-data-table so that the header does not scroll vertically and so that it has a vertical scroll bar. The horizontal scroll bar seems to happen automatically and is specific to the table rather than the page.

Without the CSS the vertical scrolling works, though obviously not the horizontal scrolling as the Account column scrolls off screen to the left.

With the CSS the account numbers stay in position, but the headings still scroll to the left, so eg Jan replaces Account. Also when scrolling down, the Account Numbers scroll up to overwrite Account. It is closer to a solution than the basics provided by Vuetify.

I also saw the example from someone who had cloned vuetify and modified it to include fixed columns and grouping. However, I was not sure whether that was vuetify 1.5 or 2 and I have already had issues with seeing examples on 1.5 and then finding that they don't work on vue 2 which I am using as there were so many breaking changes. Like you I am also wary of adopting something that may not be supported.

I am surprised that Vuetify did not include this. It must be a pretty common requirement. I have seen an enhancement request for Vuetify 3, but it is too early to adopt that and presumably it would also mean adopting Vue 3.

Regards

Paul Simon

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! hallelujah

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an approach to this that works. [Another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836604/fixed-header-fixed-column-table)

However, I cannot really claim it as an answer to the original question as it only works by abandoning the use of a v-data-table altogether. I ended up just putting a standard table in between v-spacer in my vuetify card. Any attempt to use even a v-simple-table added a second unnecessary horizontal scroll bar which ruined the effect.

The bit of CSS linked above does at least give fixed header(s) and fixed column(s) with none of the issues around scrolling up over the top left corner cell of other approaches I have seen.

It is also very easy to mark which headers you want fixed (usually all) and, in particular, which columns you want fixed. Note that the fixed columns should use 'th' rather than 'td'. This is ideal for my purpose since my data source is multi-dimensional and returns row headers and then cells with numbers eg

```
                     Actual Actual  Budget Budget 
Country   Product    Jan    Feb      Jan    Feb
UK        Widget1     50    60        70     20
UK        Widget2     60    80        90    100
USA       Widget1     90    80        10     90
```

In the example above all the following are 'th'

Actual, Budget, Jan, Feb
Country, Product

Only the number cells are 'td'

As you can see, all you need to do is to mark the 'th' in the html with class="fixed" so unlike other approaches it works for an arbitrary number of columns rather than just the left most column.

I am an expert in multi-dimensional modelling, and certainly not an expert in CSS, but I modified the CSS in the linked example a little. My CSS is as follows:

```
<style scoped>

  .table {
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    width:90%;
    max-width:100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }

  thead,
  tbody {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  tbody {
    height: 200px;
  }

  th {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-left: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-color: black;
  }

  td,
  th {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  .fixed {
    position: sticky;
    width: 5em;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  td:not(.fixed) {
    z-index: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Instead of giving a fixed width for the table, I used %. I know that not all browsers support this but this is going to be an internal application. It is not a shopping site.

I also took the z-indexes down from 9999,999,0 to 2,1,0 as without this it tended to wind up on top of the Vuetify footer when scrolling down.

Regards

Paul Simon